# Returning a error instead of response odata .net

Tags: c#, .net, odata

I'm new to Odata have been writing an api using .net (c#) and this video https://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/odata-v4.0-part2-url-conventions.html.

The problem is that i have this constructor method like so:

```
        [EnableQuery]
    public ObjectResult<InclusionWorkBookResult> GetInclusionWorkBooks()
    {
        string query = this.Url.Request.RequestUri.Query;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "");
        }
        return db.GetInclusionWorkBookData();
    }
```

As you will be able to see, the idea is that it returns a Forbidden error code if the user does not specify a query (this is to force them to filter as the full data set is millions of rows).
However this does not work because the Request.CreateErrorRespons is a HttpResponseMessage and the get returns ObjectResult.

I know you can get a forbidden error when querying odata (by messing up the url query).

My question is this:
How can i return a custom error message without messing up the return headder of the GET?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can return IHttpActionResult instead, eg:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetInclusionWorkBooks()
{
    string query = this.Url.Request.RequestUri.Query;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
    return Ok(db.GetInclusionWorkBookData());
}
```

if a query has been provided, the result will be 200(OK) and the requested data, otherwise it will be 400 Bad Request

Comment: Hi jps, Thanks for the quick answer. I had already thought of that but it dosen't work because the Odata request expects an ObjectResult<InclusionWorkBookResult>. So when I change it to return an IhttpActionResult everything works fine as far as i can trace it in the code (even the return runs) but in the response I get a 406 (Not Acceptable) message back.
I have made sure i changed the type in the WebApi.Config.cs:          "builder.EntitySet<IHttpActionResult>("InclusionWorkBooks");" This is because the odata functions actually queries the get method and sends the response back as Json.

Comment: Hi,  the change in the WepApi.Config is actually wrong. Don't change it to IHttpActionResult. Your entity set is still the InclusionWorkBookResult. You only need to change the Get method as mentioned in my answer. If you try with a tool like fiddler you'll see that you get your data in the JSON format and status OK or an empty body and status BadRequest.

Comment: That is the solution, Thanks